# QuerySet is not JSON Serializable Django

Tags: javascript, python, json, django, serialization

newbie programming here. I have a model with many rows and I would like to pass each row to javascript.

**First attempt:**

Views.py

```
events = Events.objects.filter(user_id=user_id) // filter by user_id
context = {
            "email": request.user.email,
            "login": True,
            "objects": events,
        }
return render(request, 'fullcalendar/index.html', context)
```

`Events` is the name of the table and I stored each row in `events`. Passed that into a dict called `context` which is then passed to my template. Then from my template I was able to do something like this:

```
{% for object in objects %}
    <p>event.column_name</p>
{% endfor %}
```

and that would work fine, however I can't do that in the javascript section.

```
{% for object in objects %}
    var date = object.date // assuming object has a column named date
{% endfor %}
```

**Second Attempt**

So I did some research and decided to use json.

In Views.py I made the following change:

```
return render(request, 'fullcalendar/index.html', {"obj_as_json": simplejson.dumps(context)})
```

and from this I hoped to do this:

```
var objects = {{ obj_as_json }}

for object in objects 
    //Do some stuff
```

But I got the error `QuerySet is not JSON Serializable Django`. So I looked up how to serialize objects and made the following change:

```
data = serializers.serialize('json', events.objects.all())
```

But I got following error: `'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'objects'`

Man, theres got to be a easier way to do what I want to do. Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this instead:

`data = serializers.serialize('json', events)`

The error message you got is telling you that `events` is already a QuerySet, there is no reason to try and do anything more with it.

You could also revisit your earlier attempt:

```
{% for object in objects %}
    var date = object.date // assuming object has a column named date
{% endfor %}
```

You need to actually use the Django `object` like this:

```
{% for object in objects %}
    var date = {{ object.date }}
{% endfor %}
```

The way you were doing it before `object` would simply be `undefined` and you would get the error `cannot read property date of undefined`